# Changes to $scope not applying

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a input with a datalist attached to it. The datalist gets populated as the page loads by a angular get request.

```
<input list="info" />
<datalist id="info">
  <option ng-repeat="diagnosis in diagnoses" value="{{diagnosis.data}}">
</datalist>
```

The `$http` request is a simple one:

```
$http.get('/diagnoses').then(function (response) {
    $scope.diagnoses = response.data;
})
```

and the information shows up in the source code. However the datalist does not show matching option when I type. I understand that the view needs to be updated to match the model, but calling `$scope.$digest()` throws an error instead.

> $rootScope:inprog Action Already In Progress

And calling `$scope.$apply()` does nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: You don't appear to be using `$scope.diagnoses` at all in your template. You do use `$scope.info` though

Comment: It actually is what I am using. I just typed in the generic function without thinking about it. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

You should use

```
  <option ng-repeat="data in diagnoses" value="data">
```

Comment: I am actually using that. I just typed in the generic function with generic variables without thinking. I've edited the post to reflect that.

Comment: Can you create a plunker?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I was a fool. I did not realize I had a hyphen in one of my properties that I was trying to display because it was coming from a MongoDB database. Removing the hyphen from the property name fixed everything.